# How many bit strings can be made with six 0's AND eight 1's?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This was a question I had on an exam the other night. I was really stumped by this question on the exam, and I'm still having trouble figuring it out. When doing this type of problem, there's usually a set length, but this question asks for any length, and two different elements. I thought this could've been a stars and bars problem C(n+r-1, n-1), but I don't think that works.

The question is also kind of confusing. Is it asking for any type of bit string as long as you are choosing from six 0's and eight 1's. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Edit: Just wanted to clarify that when I asked the professor about this question during the exam, he elaborated that it can be of any length, including the null string.

Comment: "Length $n$ Bitstrings" such as the set of length-4 bitstrings $\{0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,\dots,1111\}$ are sequences of length $n$ where each entry in the sequence is either $0$ or $1$.  The order of the entries in the string matter.  The number of length $n$ bit strings with exactly $k$ 0's and $n-k$ 1's should be well known as being the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: The length can range from the null string to length 14.

Comment: So then, you are asking for the number of bitstrings that can be made with **up to** six 0's and **up to** eight 1's?  not the number with **exactly** six 0's and eight 1's?  That is a very different problem.

Comment: This was my trouble during the exam. Nothing like this ever appeared in my homework. Based on my interpretation, I believe it is asking how many bit strings can be formed of size 0-14, using up to 6 0's, or up to 8 1's, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you have to use all the 14 bits to make a string.

In that case you have to choose the 6 positions of the 0's out of the 14 possible positions, which gives you ${14 \choose 6} = 3003$ choices.

**EDIT**

If you are allowed to construct strings of size less than 14 (which means that you don't use all the bits), you would get
$\sum_{n=0}^6 \sum_{m=0}^8 {n+m \choose n}$ choices. And you can simplify this sum using twice the hockey-stick identity.

$$\sum_{n=0}^6 \sum_{m=0}^8 {n+m \choose n}=\sum_{n=0}^6 {n+9 \choose n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^6 {n+9 \choose 8}=\sum_{n=0}^7 {n+8 \choose 8}-{8 \choose 8}={16 \choose 9}-1=11439$$

Comment: This question on the exam was just worded in a confusing manner. This was my first thought C(14,6) until the professor told me that the length can range from the null string to length 14.

Comment: @twentyfifthnight I edited my answer accordingly to your comment